# PhoneGap for Windows Phone doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I tried to start programming a Windows Phone 7 app with PhoneGap but after copying 'PhoneGapStarter.zip' to the folder described in http://phonegap.com/start#wp and clicking 'PhoneGapStarter" while trying to create a new project in Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone, instead of creating the project the following error is displayed:

> C:\Users\ ...\AppData\Local\Temp\gttg1doh.nd4\Temp\PhoneGapStarter4.csproj(117,3): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuiId\Microsoft\Silverlight for Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Siverlight.WindowsPhone71.Overrides.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the `<Import>` declaration is correct and that the file exists on disk.

I checked this file and I saw that the file 'Microsoft.Siverlight.WindowsPhone.Overrides.targets' (without '71') does exist, but the requested one with '71' doesn't.

Does anyone have an idea what I could do to make PhoneGap work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked my own installation but found the mentioned file. My guess would be that you either have not the latest Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (for "Mango"), which is essential for PhoneGap because the previous version doesn't support HTML5 - or your SDK installation is corrupt. Try re-downloading the latest tools, uninstall your current installation and re-install them. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Do you happen to know if/how I can check whether I have the latest version?

Comment: Ok, you were right! Old installation. The new install file is called `vm_web2.exe` while the one I had installed was called `vm_web.exe`, that made me realize I did have an old version. So thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

You could have checked if you are using the latest version of the SDK by looking into "Help" - "About Microsoft Visual Studio" and in the "Installed Products" textbox is either the "Windows Phone SDK 7.0" or "... 7.1"

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you need the Windows Phone Mango SDK along with PhoneGap templates to get it to work .

You can find some articles on how to use PhoneGap in Windows Phone from the below link

http://windowsphonerocks.com/category/developerarticles/phonegap/

Answer (score 0):

Yap uninstalling and reinstalling the 7.1 update solves this issue; also dont forget to install the January patch too

www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23854